# Profile edits change dates on historic information

Tags: contacts, profile, dates

This client runs an urban gleaning program, harvesting fruit from residential trees and providing fruit to low income communities. A key piece of data is how much fruit is donated from each tree owner annually.

[image: typical harvest collection data]

This user adds a new harvest set to the contact, each time they donate fruit. This has been working, as you can see in the example, for several years.

However, this year, when the admin attempts to update/add harvest data, the system seems to be changing the historic to (updating to no older than last year).
[image: Edit harvest screen]

The second example, shows the same 2017 harvest record but the system has changed the date to 2019 (not user input). Upon testing, even manually changing the date back to the correct dates, does not work. As far as I know, the only way to add a new harvest, requires editing the profile data and adding a new harvest at the bottom of the records.

Can we get the edit screen to respect the historic dates or can we find another way to input the data, which does not endanger the historic data?

Comment: Are those fields included in a profile or its under contact summary page?

Comment: Those are from the contact summary page. I inherited this site. I thought of putting the profile that feeds the summary in to a protected page (WordPress), but in testing, the contact search is not working. Still tinkering. Apparently, this has been the client's workflow.

Comment: Can you change the 'Display Style' of the custom group to tab with table?

Comment: not much help but my recommendation would be to discuss switching to using Activities for storing the data

Comment: check you Date Format settings?

Comment: It's an older site and cleaning issues as quickly as I can. I'm not sure how the tab vs table or date formatting would impact the issue.  If I just run the update "bad things" happen. So, I'm cleaning up what I have before I update the site. I will take all of this advice to heart as I circle back to this issue.